# Spring mvc jquery doesn't work after redirect?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I have a web app, using spring mvc. The home page is displaying correctly(the jquery slider is displayed properly). When I try to go to another page the url path is recognized all right and the page is displayed as expected but without the jquery( the slider content is displayed as if jquery is not recognized).

The controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/menu", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listMenu(Model model) {
    ...
    return "menu";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "menu/category/{cName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listCategory(@PathVariable("cName")String category, Model model) {
              ....
    return "menu/category";
}
```

I use tiles

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition extends="default" name="menu">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/menu/menu.jspx" />
    </definition>
    <definition extends="default" name="menu/category">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/menu/category.jspx" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

When I go to .../menu url the jquery slider is still displayed fine , when to ...menu/category/name the above problem appears even with menu.jspx and category.jspx having the same content. Please help me!

The links to css and scripts are in the default.jspx which is the layout of the site ,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/banner/js/jquery.cslider.js"><jsp:text/></script>
```

I tried with < spring:url > as well

Comment: What is the link to the jquery source in your page?

Comment: The links to css and scripts are in the default.jspx which is the layout of the site , <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/banner/js/jquery.cslider.js"><jsp:text/></script>

Comment: Please edit your question and add that detail there. Also, do you have an appropriate resource handler?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably has to do with the path of the views you are using and the path of the javascript resources. The paths to the javascript files need to either be absolute in which case they wouuld be the same in the two view files, or relative in which case they will not be same

Answer (score 0):

Try to add static resource configuration like below:

```
<mvc:resources order="12" location="/css/" mapping="/css/**"/>
<mvc:resources order="13" location="/js/" mapping="/js/**"/>
<mvc:resources order="14" location="/images/" mapping="/images/**"/>
```